# Protobuf permission issue when install grpc

Tags: cmake, grpc

I am following the instructions from https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/

in order to install grpc using cmake, but I run into a permission issue.

```
Running gRPC C++ protocol buffer compiler on src/proto/grpc/reflection/v1alpha/reflection.proto

/bin/sh: 1: /home/user/external/grpc/cmake/build/third_party/protobuf/protoc-3.19.4.0: Permission denied
```

What could cause this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue upgrading grpc's code from v1.46.3 to v1.48.0.